# Great-Uncle Alfred's Letter Sequence

Tags: pattern, letter-sequence

My Great-Uncle Alfred loves sequences and likes to test me with them whenever I visit.
The other day, with a flourish, "Voilà!", he presented me a piece of paper with the following sequence,

> UI, AI, EEI, EUI, EEI, AEI, ?

"What comes next?" he asked.

"I'm not sure", I replied, "but I would guess it probably ends with the letter **I**".

"Wrong!", he exclaimed, with a cackle.

**Can you tell what comes next in the sequence?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Next comes:

> **IAE**

Why? Because these are:

> the **vowels in the days of the week in French**!
>
>  L**U**ND**I** (Monday), M**A**RD**I** (Tuesday), M**E**RCR**E**D**I** (Wednesday), J**EU**D**I** (Thursday), V**E**NDR**E**D**I** (Friday), S**A**M**E**D**I** (Saturday).
>
>  Next comes D**I**M**A**NCH**E** for Sunday, with no I at the end!

The hint is:

> Alfred's use of "Voilà", a French word, suggesting that the French language may be important...

Comment: Amazing @Stiv. So fast. One of these days they will come up with a puzzle that will take you more than a day to solve!!! :)

Comment: @DrD Haha, thanks :) This kind of question (like many of your Grandpa's...) is exactly 'my cup of tea' - something short-and-sweet, which requires you to ransack the corners of your mind for a piece of information that *surely must be in there somewhere* and apply it in a different way. Here for me the 'aha' moment was noting the number of terms in the sequence and the hint word I mention above...

Comment: Correct, as always, and very quick! And yes, very much inspired by the grandpa-style puzzles of @DrD